# Python Scrapy - Execute code after spider exits

Tags: python, scrapy

I am not able to find an answer for that question. How can I execute a python code after a scrapy spider exits:

I did the following inside the function which parses the response (def parse_item(self, response):) :
 self.my_function()
Than I defined my_function(), but the problem is that it is still inside the loop of the spider. My main idea is to execute a given code in a function outside the spider's loop with the gathered data.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Use the function [closed](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-closed) of the Scrapy class as follows:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # some attributes
    spider_attr = []

    def parse(self, response):
        # do your logic here
        # page_text = response.xpath('//text()').extract()
        self.spider_attr.append(whatever)

    def closed(self, reason):
        # will be called when the crawler process ends
        # any code 
        # do something with collected data 
        for i in self.spider_attr: 
            print(i)
```

Comment: Is there a way to provide the gathered data to that function ("closed")?

Comment: you can add attributes to the class MySpider. Then access those attributes inside the method closed() by `self.attributename`